# How can I express "to check in" at an airport?

Tags: word-choice

Last time I went through an airport, I got asked questions I hadn't prepared for.  So I'm going through airport vocabulary, sentences, questions, etc. with ChatGPT.  ChatGPT gives me

> [CC-CEDICT](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?wdqb=%E5%80%BC%E6%9C%BA): 值机 (zhí​jī​) (airline) check-in / to check in

but yesterday, I said this to my friend and she got confused.  I don't believe I mispronounced it; perhaps it's too technical, or maybe she just didn't hear me properly.  I asked ChatGPT about this, and it gave me the alternative 办理登机手续 which (while longer) seems easier to understand.

**Question**: How can I express "to check in" at an airport?

Comment: 登机 is pretty good as a verb

Comment: @Mou某 doesn't that mean _board_ an airplane by default? Is there some way to distinguish these two very different tasks in Chinese?

Comment: How about 办理登机手续 -->办登机 = go through the steps to board a plane

Comment: Never heard of 值机, not even at Chinese airports.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Very colloquial but to board the plane would just be 上飞机. Obviously these are for oral communication and to be easily understood. Probably wouldn’t work in more formal/written circumstances.

Comment: @Mou某 the question-asker is not asking about how to say "board the plane". They're asking about checking in at the front desk and getting their boarding pass.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Yeah that's 登机. I was subsequently following up your question.

Comment: @Mou某 but 登机 can also mean to board. The OP is asking for something that means "to check in" and does not also mean "to board".

Answer (score 4):

"**Check-i**n" literally means "(向航空公司) **報到**", and the goal is to start the procedure to board a plane, 办理登机手续 is a correct translation, or you can simplify it to 办登机

Check-in procedure:

1. 领取登机证 = Obtain a boarding pass (at the airline counter or using a kiosk machine)
2. 托付行李 = Check Luggage
3. 过海关 = Go through customs

Answer (score 1):

"值机" is definitely understandable for those fly a lot. This is a screenshot from "东方航空"(Eastern Airline), and you can see "选座值机" here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with 值机.

您乘坐的航班在18号柜台办理值机。
You should check in at desk 18.

Answer (score 0):

The verb 值機 indeed means check in, I believe the confusion could have been a context issue.  For example maybe your friend thought you were talking about checking in at a hotel, checking your bags, chekcing in with the hostess to physically get on the plane, or whatnot. This will lead to confusion when you talk about something different from what they expected after that moment.

If context itself is clear enough, additional clarification may not be needed at all.  An example of something that could be used for clarification is 值機收到我機票, or other  similar phrasing.  I often mention context being king in chinese to refer to how the topic comment nature of chinese often leaves a lot of vocab out that would be required in english.  It goes the opposite way too, if you context isn't well established you may need to specify something in your comment for clarity that wouldn't be required when that context is clearer.  Just food for thought (◐‿◑)﻿

---

I will not tell you not to use Chatgpt, its your personal choice.  I will just make a side note that this is a perfect example of a time chatgpt wasn't wrong, but was really clear enough to facilitate learning.  There are also many times chatgpt will completely make up things out of the blue for no reason.  If you want to use it go for it, just have a mental note that it has been recognized as a less than ideal source for new knowledge like languages.  Best of luck o(∩_∩)o